# Streaming playback stuttering issues after switching to DirectSound

Tags: audio-streaming, naudio, directsound

I've been using NAudio and specifically the old WaveOut output API for my Spotify client app, [Blindspot](http://blindspot.codeplex.com). And all was harmonious and well. Or at least as far as I could tell.

Recently, though, I switched to using DirectSound, since it would allow me to easily and efficiently let the user choose and change their output device and keep these settings between app and computer restarts, which was a requested feature.

All worked fine on my dev machine, my laptop. So I toodled on and installed it on another machine I've been using as a test machine for sanity checking before releases. I'm glad I did on this occasion, as the sound quality has massively degraded since the switch to DirectSound. I'm getting a sort of clipping sound every few seconds or so on most tracks. I get bad stuttering if ever my CPU (or possibly just .NET) gets particularly busy and it generally just feels worse, even though this API is supposed to be newer and better. I didn't notice these symptoms on either machine when using WaveOut before.

For a bit of background info on both machines. Both are running Windows 7, both 64 bit, both with DX11. The dev machine (which it works fine on) is an I7 ultrabook with an SSD, whilst the machine it doesn't work on is an I5 desktop and no SSD, though I'd be surprised if that's the issue. Interestingly, on the machine that it doesn't work on, the problem goes away if I use a set of USB headphones with their own sound card in instead of the normal headphone jack. However, using the old version of my program before the switch to DirectSound still runs perfectly fine without the USB headphones, so I don't think it's exclusively that.

What am I doing wrong? Is it my code that's wrong, or is DirectSound perhaps not the right tool for this job?

I'm not going to post all my code here, since I've got several classes that deal with playback in this project. But I'll post some exerts showing what I'm doing. I also apologize if this isn't the nicest audio playback code. I confess I'm new to audio playback above simply playing back sounds or at the most playing them back in 3D space. Streaming is a new area for me.

Edit: This code has been simplified as suggested. Looks much nicer, right?

```
// this is the main object that controls playback in the application
public class PlaybackManager : IDisposable
{
    private IWavePlayer waveOut;
    private Guid _playbackDeviceID;
    ...
    public void AddBytesToPlayingStream(byte[] bytes)
    {
        if (bufferedWaveProvider != null)
            bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
    ...
    // modified from NAudio sample code but working with incoming bytes
    private void GetStreaming(object state)
    {
        this.fullyDownloaded = false;

        try
        {
            do
            {
                if (bufferedWaveProvider == null)
                {
                    this.bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(new WaveFormat(44100, 2));
                    this.bufferedWaveProvider.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20); // allow us to get well ahead of ourselves
                    Logger.WriteDebug("Creating buffered wave provider");
                }
                // in case its still null
                if (bufferedWaveProvider == null)
                    continue;

                var freeBufferBytes = bufferedWaveProvider.BufferLength - bufferedWaveProvider.BufferedBytes;
                if (freeBufferBytes < bufferedWaveProvider.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond / 4)
                {
                    Logger.WriteDebug("Buffer getting full, taking a break");
                    Thread.Sleep(450);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(250);
            } while (playbackState != StreamingPlaybackState.Stopped);
            Logger.WriteDebug("Playback stopped");
        }
        finally
        {
            // no post-processing work here, right?
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (playbackState != StreamingPlaybackState.Stopped)
        {
            if (this.waveOut == null && this.bufferedWaveProvider != null)
            {
                Logger.WriteDebug("Creating WaveOut Device");
                this.waveOut = CreateWaveOut();
                waveOut.PlaybackStopped += waveOut_PlaybackStopped;
                this.volumeProvider = new VolumeWaveProvider16(bufferedWaveProvider);
                this.volumeProvider.Volume = this.volume;
                waveOut.Init(volumeProvider);
            }
            if (bufferedWaveProvider != null)
            {
                var bufferedSeconds = bufferedWaveProvider.BufferedDuration.TotalSeconds;
                // make it stutter less if we buffer up a decent amount before playing
                if (bufferedSeconds < 0.5 && this.playbackState == StreamingPlaybackState.Playing && !this.fullyDownloaded)
                {
                    this.playbackState = StreamingPlaybackState.Buffering;
                    waveOut.Pause();
                    Logger.WriteDebug(String.Format("Paused to buffer, waveOut.PlaybackState={0}", waveOut.PlaybackState));
                }
                else if (bufferedSeconds > secondsToBuffer && this.playbackState == StreamingPlaybackState.Buffering)
                {
                    waveOut.Play();
                    Logger.WriteDebug(String.Format("Started playing, waveOut.PlaybackState={0}", waveOut.PlaybackState));
                    this.playbackState = StreamingPlaybackState.Playing;
                }
                // stop when right at the end
                else if (this.fullyDownloaded && bufferedSeconds == 0)
                {
                    Logger.WriteDebug("Reached end of stream");
                    Stop();

                    // handle end of track logic
                    if (OnEndOfTrack != null)
                        OnEndOfTrack();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private IWavePlayer CreateWaveOut()
    {
        // used to be return new WaveOutEvent();
        return new DirectSoundOut(PlaybackDeviceID);
    }
    ...
}
```

If it helps to see the code in full and in context, you can view the [new code](http://blindspot.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Blindspot.Playback/PlaybackManager.cs), or view a [diff of the changes](http://blindspot.codeplex.com/SourceControl/diff/file/view/697ecbf29891d1b24cb89dfff697e7557d3ae055?fileId=Blindspot.Playback%2FPlaybackManager.cs&olderChangeSetId=805ee29bd7bd26cfc1556e7b45320923dc18468e) from the older version.

Of course, you're also welcome to download the source code and try using the Blindspot.Playback project to play files by artifically sending it bytes into the Playback Manager. If your machine is similarly afflicted, this should cause you to experience stuttery behaviour.

Any help gratefully received, as I suspect this one's a complex problem. Either that or I'm an idiot and I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: you seem to have a lot of layers of buffering going on. Have you tried just putting all audio received straight into a BufferedWaveProvider as soon as it arrives? You might find that works quite well.

Comment: I think I tried it back when I first wrote this. I think it got full, hence the layers of buffering. Is there any way to do this without it getting full?

Comment: Never mind, I spotted the bit where I set the length of the buffer. I can't remember why I only made it 20 seconds before, it was a long time ago. I won't be able to tell whether this resolves the issue until Monday, but initial tests seem to indicate this works in favour of all the wrapping I put around the buffer. Thanks for responding, if this works it will simplify my code significantly.

Comment: @Mark: No joy on it resolving the stuttering DirectSound issues. But it hasn't negatively impacted the situation either and the much simpler code can only help. Thanks again.